# Partial content streamed from Java URL connection

Tags: java, url, curl

I am having trouble consistently getting the entire body of requests made to https://trainingapply.grants.gov/apply/opportunities/schemas/applicant/PKG00037270/Project.xsd from my Java application.  Sometimes, I get the entire body.  Other times, I get the first 4072 characters and the body ends.  I have tried the following approaches:

```
//core java
try {
  URLConnection urlConnection = new URL(schemaUrl).openConnection();
  StringBuilder schema = new StringBuilder();
  String line;

  try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"))) {
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      schema.append(line);
    }
  }

  return schema.toString();
} catch (IOException e) {
  //[error handling]
}
```

```
//Apache commons
return IOUtils.toString(new URL(schemaUrl), "UTF-8");
```

And using the Apache HttpComponents lib with the same result.  Oddly enough, Postman, my browser and curl all return a consistent and complete body, so this has to be java specific.  I'm using java 1.8.0_181.

Interestingly, when curling this url, there is a network packet boundary right at 4072 bytes into the content that looks like this:

```
<= Recv data, 4072 bytes (0xfe8)
0000: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
...
...
0fb4:                <xsd:complexType>
0fd6:                   
<= Recv data, 2688 bytes (0xa80)
0000:  <xsd:sequence>
0011: ..             <xsd:element name="SubApplicationGroupID" type="x
```

It is clear to me that these other clients are handling this request correctly while the built-in java primitives are not always fetching to the end of the content length declared in the headers.  Here are the headers for your reference as well:

```
=> Send header, 149 bytes (0x95)
0000: GET /apply/opportunities/schemas/applicant/PKG00037270/Project.x
0040: sd HTTP/1.1
004d: Host: trainingapply.grants.gov
006d: User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
0086: Accept: */*
0093: 
<= Recv header, 17 bytes (0x11)
0000: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<= Recv header, 24 bytes (0x18)
0000: Connection: Keep-Alive
<= Recv header, 37 bytes (0x25)
0000: Date: Thu, 21 Feb 2019 20:50:04 GMT
<= Recv header, 18 bytes (0x12)
0000: Pragma: no-cache
<= Recv header, 22 bytes (0x16)
0000: Content-Length: 6760
<= Recv header, 39 bytes (0x27)
0000: Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
<= Recv header, 40 bytes (0x28)
0000: Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
<= Recv header, 33 bytes (0x21)
0000: X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
<= Recv header, 21 bytes (0x15)
0000: X-ORACLE-DMS-RID: 0
<= Recv header, 33 bytes (0x21)
0000: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
<= Recv header, 114 bytes (0x72)
0000: Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=M6AR0orf2aDdcnmBu-LHOBRL4pjuVTRhx_n-uj-2a
0040: p7OSBVfCuVG!1960121785; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
<= Recv header, 66 bytes (0x42)
0000: X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID: 7241b3bd-75bf-48a0-85e6-57059f2a08da-007a0021
<= Recv header, 35 bytes (0x23)
0000: X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3
<= Recv header, 29 bytes (0x1d)
0000: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
<= Recv header, 45 bytes (0x2d)
0000: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
<= Recv header, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000:
```

Any ideas what might be going on here?

Comment: Why are you using readline? Use the stupid scanner tricks to read the whole file.

Comment: Happy to try that... which stupid tricks are you referring to?  We're also talking about an http request, not a file on the local machine.

Comment: @jwiggs, Try to check tips from this article [Download a File From an URL in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-download-file). In case it still will not work, please let us know.

Comment: Yep... I have tried #2 and 2 other libraries.  They all consistently cut off content.  My example above is a slight change from #2 in that I was investigating the content length and other headers so switched to a URLConnection instead.

Comment: Soory @MichałZiober, I forgot to tag you on my response.  I definitely went through those methods, particularly #2.

Comment: @jwiggs, I have check your code and given `URL` and it works for me all the time. Maybe it is a network problem, something like firewall.

Comment: Thanks @MichałZiober, I'm guessing this has something to do with rate limiting or something else.  I am pulling 5 of these down back-to-back... I'll test more around that theory.  Thanks for checking for me.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my application was making many calls to this general service in rapid succession and sometimes to the same url multiple times.  In that scenario, it appears that the server was closing the connection and therefore the response was truncated.  I placed caching around fetching these urls and the problem seems to have gone away, so nothing to do with the libraries or how I was using them, but the network connection was closing without any feedback or warning.